# Data consolidation from different cells depending on variable in Excel

Tags: excel, validation, variables, excel-formula

I'm sure there is a simple answer, but I have literally looked for hours, to no avail. Here's the scenario...

If I have 20 marbles:
`Column A` is 20 rows long, each cell containing the value `1`.
`Column B` is a drop-down menu requiring a user to select `Red` `Blue` or `Yellow`
If I select `Red` for 10 cells in column `B,` then I need cell E1 to reflect a value of "10"
If I select `Blue` for 6 cells in column `B`, then I need cell E2 to reflect a value of `6`
If I select `Yellow` for 4 cells in column `B`, then I need cell E3 to reflect a value of "4"

I need to automatically populate cells in colum E (my consolidated data) with a total from column A, depending on the information selected in the drop-down menu in column B. I'm assuming there is a code I can enter in E1 to total the value of cells in column A if the value in cell to the right is "Red".

This needs to be able to hold true if I want to change to the following scenario....
Column A is 20 rows long, each cell containing different values.
Column B is a drop-down menu requiring a user to select "Red" "Blue" or "Yellow"

```
A1 relfects "3"       
A2 reflects "4"
A3 reflects "2"
B1 reflects "Red"
B2 reflects "Red"
B3 reflects "Red"
E1 needs to reflect "9"
```

I'm still learning a lot, so I'm not very familiar. As I said, I'm sure this isn't too difficult, I just can't seem to find it. I though I was on the right track with the "ADDIF" code, but I couldn't figure the variables. Perhaps I didn't know how to "Google" the question. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel 2003 - 2010

Use SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(A2:T2,"RED",A1:T1)

=SUMIF(SEARCH RANGE, MATCH VALUE, SUM RANGE)
```

If you don't need a value in row A, use COUNTIF:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:T2,"RED")
=COUNTIF(SEARCH RANGE, MATCH VALUE)
```

COUNTIF assumes 1 each, so it wouldn't hold true in the second problem you had, but wanted to make sure you knew.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! That wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but you certainly pointed me in the right direction. For anyone that might be curious, the code i was looking for was.. 
`=SUMIF(B1:B200,"red",A1:A200)`
Many thanks to Pirion to the help. I couldn't have figured it out without your help!